# Getting unsupportedEncodingException

Tags: php, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to consume PHP web service using Android. Establishing the connection to the server via `HttpClient`. When I'm executing the code I'm getting HTML document instead of getting JSON String to parse it further. Not able to figure out where exactly I'm lacking.
In URL, when I'm removing .php extension getting  null and when adding .php extension getting HTML Documnet only. Code is given below,

```
public class ServerConnector {


    //HttpResponse response;
    public String postRegistrationData(UserRegistrationBean userRegistration){
        final String URL = "http://webserviceaddress.com/respondents/Efair/registrations/add.php";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
        try{
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            Log.d("Name", userRegistration.getName());
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", userRegistration.getName()));
            Log.d("C_Name", userRegistration.getCompany_name());
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company_name", userRegistration.getCompany_name()));
            Log.d("Email", userRegistration.getE_mail());
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", userRegistration.getE_mail()));
            Log.d("Product", userRegistration.getProd_of_interest());
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_of_interest", userRegistration.getProd_of_interest()));
            Log.d("Mobile ", userRegistration.getMobile_no());
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_no", userRegistration.getMobile_no()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", "India"));
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8);
            httpPost.setEntity(ent);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            String bufferedStrChunk = null;
            while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                data.append(bufferedStrChunk);
            }
            System.out.println("Server Response - "+ data.toString());
            return data.toString();

        }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            Log.d("RegistrationResponse", e.toString());
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("RegistrationResponse", e.toString());
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("RegistrationResponse", e.toString());
        }
        return null;


    }

}
```

Logcat : 
01-21 14:01:40.637: I/System.out(1337): Server Response -                                         Blog            Errors                                                                                                        LoginSign-Up                                        Blog

### Not Found

**Error:**     The requested address **'/respondents/Efair/registrations/add.php'** was not found on this server.

Blog

This is how I'm calling above method.

```
registrationResponse = connector.postRegistrationData(userRegistrationBean);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), registrationResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`userRegistrationBean` is nothing but a data container here.

Please help to sort out this problem. Trying since yesterday but not getting proper way to solve it.

Comment: Please post your logCat so we can see where this exception is thrown

Comment: How to show Logcat here.. It's very large

Comment: JUst show the relevant part.  Save it to a file then copy and paste.

Comment: Server response is HTML Document whenever adding .php extension in URL otheriwse returning nothing. Html Doc is large enough to post it here.. Please Help

Comment: Not able to paste here... Any other option to post the logcat here...?

Comment: why can you not edit your question and post the relevant part of logCat in?

Comment: I have added the logcat and this is the url i'm using..... http://203.92.33.66/respondents/Efair/registrations/add.php

Comment: can someone help me on above stated problem

Comment: You are saying you get a `unsupportedEncodingException` but you are also saying you are getting a not found error.  Which one is it?  If it is the not found, then how on earth can we help fix that?

Comment: @user2310289, I sorted out unsupportedEncodingException now. My problem is I got a URL without any extension(but webservice is developed in php). Now whenever I removing .php extension from the URL niether i'm getting any error nor any json String to parse it further and when I'm adding .php extension i'm getting not found message. same URL(without any extension) working fine with iOS apps so I can't consider it as back end team lacking. Seriously I'm not able to figure out this problem. please help me on this. The URL i'm using here in my app, I have already posted in above comments.

Comment: @user2310289 i'm getting successful status code 200

Answer (score 0):

Always after a POST check for the status code as below.

check

```
HttpResponse httpResp = client.execute(response);
int code = httpResp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I guess that you are getting a 500 series error.

Comment: No I'm not getting 500 series error in fact I'm getting status code 200 for this.

Comment: But no data and no error?  try monitoring with wireshark.  Maybe server is not sending you any response?

Comment: Could you tell me how to solve this problem. Now I'm getting this message in logcat  01-22 11:37:31.045: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol.

Comment: I solved the issue. It was server issue. server was not sending response for my query. Thanks for the help.